# How to enumerate icons in My Computer

Tags: c++, winapi, citrix

Citrix XenApp adds icons for client-side drives into My Computer view when Explorer is launched from the remote desktop.

How the heck do I enumerate these icons? Google is useless, because "icon", "other" and "computer" are too generic terms. I can enumerate all of the network drives with WNetOpenEnum etc, but I haven't figured out how to get any of the extra info in this view through that.

Namely, I'd like to figure out which ones of the drives are removable on the client side. This info is readily available in the screenshotted view attached, but how do I find the same info via C++?

[image: Citrix client view]

Comment: `IShellFolder` and friends.

Comment: Enumerate `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` followed by `GetDriveType()` on each one. `DRIVE_REMOVABLE` tells you if the drive is removable but that will include USB drives etc.

Comment: IShellFolder was the missing keyword, it's working great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/30/10202076.aspx solved this for me. Just replaced recycle bin with CSIDL_DRIVES

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"**Provide context for links**: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Comment: As in this case the given link is broken and not accessible any more...

Comment: Microsoft moves contents around every few years. The blog post is here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110830-00/?p=9773